# Commit every x minutes, mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I'd like to save every changes on the C++ connector every x minutes, because I'm coding a server that may have lots of transactions, and I don't want to spam my mysql server. 
I'm also using a connection pool. So, if I turn autocommit on off, and start a thread that will commit everything on each connections of the connection pool every x minutes, would that work ?

What if a row is modified twice by two distinct connections ? :/

Comment: You must commit exactly when your transaction is done. Not before, not after, and certainly not at a random point in time unrelated to the work that needs to be committed.

Comment: @Mat Okey, so is there a way to achieve what I'm talking about in my post ? (Saving every x minutes)

Comment: If you want to save the state of something every X minutes, then run a transaction that saves that state (and commits) every X minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You must commit exactly when your transaction is done. Not before, not after, and certainly not at a random point in time unrelated to the work that needs to be committed.

Comment: Why have you copied a comment made by @Mat?